# Cannot set property 'max' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm making a dice display app using typescript, I am still fairly new at learning it but I think I am picking up on it well, however I am am stuck at figuring out this issue with this dice app I am working on. The aim of the app is to roll the dice with min number being 1 and the max number being set on window load which is currently 99 for it to then generate and display a random number on the index along with the min and max values. However when I compile and go to test it I get this error in the console:

> **main.ts:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'max' of undefined at window.onload (main.ts:66)**

window.onload @ main.ts:66
load (async)

(anonymous) @ main.ts:63

And in the console on vsCode I get this in my main.ts file
[errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aelc1.png)

```js
"use strict";
class Dice {
  constructor(max) {
    this.max = max;
    this.min = 1;
  }
  get _max() {
    return this.max;
  }
  get _min() {
    return this.min;
  }
  set _max(max) {
    this.max = max;
  }
  set _min(min) {
    this.min = min;
  }
  roll() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.max) + this.min;
  }
}
class Display {
  constructor(vm) {
    this.max = vm.max.toString();
    this.min = vm.min.toString();
    this.rand = vm.rand.toString();
  }
  update() {
    document.getElementById("random").innerText = this.rand;
    if (this.min !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("min").innerText = this.min;
    }
    if (this.max !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("max").innerText = this.max;
    }
  }
}
window.onload = () => {
  let ukDice = new Dice(99);
  let viewModel;
  viewModel.max = ukDice._max;
  viewModel.min = ukDice._min;
  viewModel.rand = ukDice.roll();
  let output = new Display(viewModel);
  output.update();
};
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="random"></div>
  <div id="min"></div>
  <div id="max"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Main.ts:

```
interface viewModel {
  max: number;
  min: number;
  rand: number;
}

class Dice {

  private max: number;
  private min: number;

  constructor(max: number) {
    this.max = max;
    this.min = 1;
  }

  get _max(): number {
    return this.max;
  }

  get _min(): number {
    return this.min;
  }

  set _max(max: number) {
    this.max = max;
  }

  set _min(min: number) {
    this.min = min;
  }

  roll() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.max) + this.min;
  }
}

class Display {

  private max: string;
  private min: string;
  private rand: string;

  constructor(vm: viewModel) {
    this.max = vm.max.toString();
    this.min = vm.min.toString();
    this.rand = vm.rand.toString();
  }

  update() {
    document.getElementById("random").innerText = this.rand;

    if (this.min !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("min").innerText = this.min;
    }

    if (this.max !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("max").innerText = this.max;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  let ukDice = new Dice(99);
  let viewModel: viewModel;
  viewModel.max = ukDice._max;
  viewModel.min = ukDice._min;
  viewModel.rand = ukDice.roll();
  let output = new Display(viewModel);
  output.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare as `let viewModel = new Display(ukDice);` and also add `this.rand = 1;` in the `Dice` constructor

```js
"use strict";
class Dice {
  constructor(max) {
    this.max = max;
    this.min = 1;
    this.rand = 1;
  }
  get _max() {
    return this.max;
  }
  get _min() {
    return this.min;
  }
  set _max(max) {
    this.max = max;
  }
  set _min(min) {
    this.min = min;
  }
  roll() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.max) + this.min;
  }
}
class Display {
  constructor(vm) {
    this.max = vm.max.toString();
    this.min = vm.min.toString();
    this.rand = vm.rand.toString();
  }
  update() {
    document.getElementById("random").innerText = this.rand;
    if (this.min !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("min").innerText = this.min;
    }
    if (this.max !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("max").innerText = this.max;
    }
  }
}
window.onload = () => {
  let ukDice = new Dice(99);
  let viewModel = new Display(ukDice);
  viewModel.max = ukDice._max;
  viewModel.min = ukDice._min;
  viewModel.rand = ukDice.roll();
  let output = new Display(viewModel);
  output.update();
};
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="random"></div>
<div id="min"></div>
<div id="max"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because viewModel is still null.

`let viewModel: viewModel;`